# Gnome-screenshot not showing prompt for setting file name in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome-screenshot

I'd like to set every screenshot name manually and choose the place to save it. The prompt was showing in Ubuntu 16.04 but is not showing in 18.04. There is no option to enable that prompt in:

```
gsettings list-keys org.gnome.gnome-screenshot
```

Comment: Not exactly.  Mapping "gnome-screenshot -i" to Shift+PrntScrn in Ubuntu 18.04 is not equivalent to Shift+PrntScrn in Ubuntu 16.04. EDIT - Ok, it's a duplicate. Why did screenshot app in 16.04 had that prompt and in 18.04 it's gone?

Comment: I totally agree with you. This kindof things might ruin the linux world.